# `zoom` CSS property and font-size in safari

Tags: css, safari, zooming, responsive, font-size

My website is kinda responsive on dektop, but when it comes to iPad or tablet-sized devices, it's awful. This doesn't come from the layout which is ok, but everything is just too BIG, making the website hard to navigate through. I think it might be useful to know that my website is a webapp in which we have pages without scrolling, I mean that all the content fits in the viewport.

I would like to zoom out the page on smaller devices, because zooming out to 75% looks pretty nice.

## Test 1

I already tried to set a `zoom` CSS property on the `:root` element:

```css
:root {
    zoom: .8;
}
```

Actually it works fine on chromium browsers, but on Safari, everything is nice except for the `font-size` that doesn't decrease. Btw it is not supported by Firefox (it's not important to me if there's no other solution).
I would like to know if there is a way to better support zoom on safari, or even a totally different way to zoom out a page

Thanks

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_reproducible_example)!

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is mainly with text sizes you can do a lot by changing your sizes to relative units. So instead of 25px for the font you could use 25vw which would base the size on the width of the viewport. This approach can run into some issues with fonts being too small or large on different screen sizes so the best practice is to use media queries based on the size of screen.

Here is an example:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  body {
    background-color: lightgreen;
  }
}
```

This would change the background to lightgreen when the size of the screen is below 480px wide. By using media queries you can write css for every screen size.

Here is a guide on media queries: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp
and on css units: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.php

Hope this helps.